# AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code using the AWS Serverless Application Model AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-sdk, aws-sam

I follow the steps described at Create a Serverless Application with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/create-sam.html

This is step by step building a lambda function with AWS SAM model.

When I execute the function locally, I got following error message:

File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

I have the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code extension installed and I can connect to any region using AWS Explorer

Any help appretiated!

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I have not configured aws for access keys and default region

On Terminal screen, you can execute

```
aws configure
```

command and provide information requested